# How api gateway should be handled with nestjs?

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I want to create an application frontend with microservices in the backend (with nestjs).

In this example, I saw the API gateway expose endpoints and call to the services in order to return the and add some logic in the API gateway after the service response.

https://github.com/danmt/microservices-basics/blob/master/api-gateway/src/app.service.ts

same for this example: https://github.com/Denrox/nestjs-microservices-example/blob/master/gateway/src/tasks.controller.ts

Every time I add new endpoint, I need to do it in the service itself and inside the API service also.

And I wonder why is that. Because sometimes developers can be confused which where to write the logic? Inside the api-gateway? or inside the service? Why should I write inside the service if I anyway write the endpoint inside the api-gateway and goto service and create a new file and write the logic there?

Especially when I develop a project for my client, and the team is not up to date with the microservice mindset (even I teach them they might forget or a new developer is entering the team).

Is it possible to just forward the request to the right service without changing the API gateway each time the endpoint of the service changed?

Is that possible with nestjs? and this is correct solution with nest?

Comment: Hello did you find any good solution for this question ?

Comment: sorry but not yet